# Is there a way to extract frames from a video file using ffmpeg to memory and make some manipulation on each frame?

Tags: c#, winforms, ffmpeg

The goal is to extract each time a frame from the video file then make histogram from the image and then to move to the next frame. this way all the frames.

The frames extraction and the histogram manipulation is working fine when the frames have saved as images on the hard disk.  but now i want to do it all in memory.

to extract the frames i'm using ffmpeg because i think it's fast enough:

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -i MyVid.mp4 -r 1 "$filename%03d.png
```

for now i'm using the ffmpeg in command prompt window.

with this command it will save on the hard disk over 65000 images(frames).
but instead saving them on the hard disk i wonder if i can make the histogram manipulation on each frame in memory instead saving all the 65000 frames to the hard disk.

then i want to find specific images using the histogram and save to the hard disk this frames.

the histogram part for now is also using files from the hard disk and not from the memory:

```
private void btnLoadHistogram_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\screenshots\", "*.jpg");

            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                sbInfo.Text = "Loading image";
                if (pbImage.Image != null)
                    pbImage.Image.Dispose();

                pbImage.Image = Image.FromFile(files[i]);//txtFileName.Text);

                Application.DoEvents();

                sbInfo.Text = "Computing histogram";
                long[] myValues = GetHistogram(new Bitmap(pbImage.Image));

                Histogram.DrawHistogram(myValues);

                sbInfo.Text = "";   
            }   
        }

        public long[] GetHistogram(System.Drawing.Bitmap picture)
        {
            long[] myHistogram = new long[256];

            for (int i=0;i<picture.Size.Width;i++)
                for (int j=0;j<picture.Size.Height;j++)
                {
                    System.Drawing.Color c  = picture.GetPixel(i,j);

                    long Temp=0;
                    Temp+=c.R;
                    Temp+=c.G;
                    Temp+=c.B;

                    Temp = (int) Temp/3;
                    myHistogram[Temp]++;
                }

            return myHistogram;
        }
```

and the code of the class of the constrol HistogramaDesenat :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Histograma
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for HistogramaDesenat.
    /// </summary>
    public class HistogramaDesenat : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.Container components = null;

        public HistogramaDesenat()
        {
            // This call is required by the Windows.Forms Form Designer.
            InitializeComponent();

            // TODO: Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent call

            this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(HistogramaDesenat_Paint);
            this.Resize+=new EventHandler(HistogramaDesenat_Resize);
        }

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
        {
            if( disposing )
            {
                if(components != null)
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
            }
            base.Dispose( disposing );
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            // 
            // HistogramaDesenat
            // 
            this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((System.Byte)(0)));
            this.Name = "HistogramaDesenat";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(208, 176);
        }
        #endregion

        private void HistogramaDesenat_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (myIsDrawing)
            {

                Graphics g = e.Graphics;
                Pen myPen = new Pen(new SolidBrush(myColor),myXUnit);
                //The width of the pen is given by the XUnit for the control.
                for (int i=0;i<myValues.Length;i++)
                {

                    //We draw each line 
                    g.DrawLine(myPen,
                        new PointF(myOffset + (i*myXUnit), this.Height - myOffset), 
                        new PointF(myOffset + (i*myXUnit), this.Height - myOffset - myValues[i] * myYUnit));

                    //We plot the coresponding index for the maximum value.
                    if (myValues[i]==myMaxValue)
                    {
                        SizeF mySize = g.MeasureString(i.ToString(),myFont);

                        g.DrawString(i.ToString(),myFont,new SolidBrush(myColor),
                            new PointF(myOffset + (i*myXUnit) - (mySize.Width/2), this.Height - myFont.Height ),
                            System.Drawing.StringFormat.GenericDefault);
                    }
                }

                //We draw the indexes for 0 and for the length of the array beeing plotted
                g.DrawString("0",myFont, new SolidBrush(myColor),new PointF(myOffset,this.Height - myFont.Height),System.Drawing.StringFormat.GenericDefault);
                g.DrawString((myValues.Length-1).ToString(),myFont, 
                    new SolidBrush(myColor),
                    new PointF(myOffset + (myValues.Length * myXUnit) - g.MeasureString((myValues.Length-1).ToString(),myFont).Width,
                    this.Height - myFont.Height),
                    System.Drawing.StringFormat.GenericDefault);

                //We draw a rectangle surrounding the control.
                g.DrawRectangle(new System.Drawing.Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black),1),0,0,this.Width-1,this.Height-1);
            }

        }

        long myMaxValue;
        private long[] myValues;
        private bool myIsDrawing;

        private float myYUnit; //this gives the vertical unit used to scale our values
        private float myXUnit; //this gives the horizontal unit used to scale our values
        private int myOffset = 20; //the offset, in pixels, from the control margins.

        private Color myColor = Color.Black;
        private Font myFont = new Font("Tahoma",10);

        [Category("Histogram Options")]
        [Description ("The distance from the margins for the histogram")]
        public int Offset
        {
            set
            {
                if (value>0)
                    myOffset= value;
            }
            get
            {
                return myOffset;
            }
        }

        [Category("Histogram Options")]
        [Description ("The color used within the control")]
        public Color DisplayColor
        {
            set
            {
                myColor = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return myColor;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// We draw the histogram on the control
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="myValues">The values beeing draw</param>
        public void DrawHistogram(long[] Values)
        {
            myValues = new long[Values.Length];
            Values.CopyTo(myValues,0);

            myIsDrawing = true;
            myMaxValue = getMaxim(myValues);

            ComputeXYUnitValues();

            this.Refresh();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// We get the highest value from the array
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Vals">The array of values in which we look</param>
        /// <returns>The maximum value</returns>
        private long getMaxim(long[] Vals)
        {
            if (myIsDrawing)
            {
                long max = 0;
                for (int i=0;i<Vals.Length;i++)
                {
                    if (Vals[i] > max)
                        max = Vals[i];
                }
                return max;
            }
            return 1;
        }

        private void HistogramaDesenat_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (myIsDrawing)
            {
                ComputeXYUnitValues();
            }
            this.Refresh();
        }

        private void ComputeXYUnitValues()
        {
            myYUnit = (float) (this.Height - (2 * myOffset)) / myMaxValue;
            myXUnit = (float) (this.Width - (2 * myOffset)) / (myValues.Length-1);
        }
    }
}
```

so in the end this is what i want to do :

- extract the frames from the video file in memory using the ffmpeg.
- instead using Directory.GetFiles i want to make the histogram manipulation on each frame from the memory that is extracted by the ffmpeg.
- each extracted frame image to use the histogram to find if there is a lightning(weather lightning) in the image.
- if there is a lightning save the frame image to the hard disk.

Comment: "extract the frames from the video file in memory" > depending on the format of the video. If it's MP4 then you're sol because FFmpeg needs to seek and can't do that with pipes. If you have raw video frames (rgb, grayscale, yuv, etc.) then yes, feed your frames with `-f rawvideo -i -` muxer. Also, any file with seek-free demuxer/decoder you can feed it through stdin as well.

Comment: You may use FFmpeg as subprocess, and reading raw video from `stdout` pipe of FFmpeg sub-process. Please edit your question, to be more clear if the video input is in memory, or in a file. In case the video is stored in file, it's simpler to use OpenCV for reading the video frame by frame. Please post a minimal code sample - most of your code sample is irrelevant for the subject of reading/decoding video frames.

Answer (score 0):

For ffmpeg, try [FFmpeg.AutoGen](https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen)
But you need learn about ffmpeg api for demuxer and decoder to get raw frame.

---

For opencv, try [emgucv](https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv) (recomend)
You can try search example somewhere like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42083893/5034139)